# Curiously recurring template patterns with additional generic types

Tags: c#, generics, crtp

Let's say I want to have a generic `Box` class that can contain something inside, so it's a `Box<T>`. `Box<T>` has a `Transform` method that returns a `Box<U>`:

```
public Box<U> Transform<U>(Func<T, U> transform)
```

So far this has been quite simple. However, I actually need an abstract `Box`, since the way the values are boxed and transformed is implementation-specific. (I can't have an interface since there are other methods that are implemented via composition of abstract methods, but this doesn't change anything anyway).

Of course, I want my overridden `Transform` methods to return an appropriate subclass of `Box`, not `Box` itself. Since return types of overriding methods are invariant in C#, I turn to the [*curiously recurring template pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (see `IComparable<T>`):

```
public abstract class Box<B, T> where B : Box<B, T>
```

Now every class I inherit from `Box<B, T>` should refer to itself or all hell breaks loose:

```
public class FooBox<T> : Box<FooBox, T>
```

However, this completely destroys the `Transform` method:

```
public abstract Box<B, U> Transform<U>(Func<T, U> transform);
```

fails to compile with `The type 'B' cannot be used as type parameter 'B' in the generic type or method 'Test.Box<B,T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'B' to 'Test.Box<B,U>'. (CS0311)`. That makes sense, since the return type is now `Box<B, U>` and B is `Box<B, T>`, which is not `Box<B, U>`.

The straightforward fix won't work:

```
public abstract Box<B, U> Transform<U>(Func<T, U> transform) where B : Box<B, U>;
```

fails to compile with `'Test.Box<B,T>.Transform<U>()' does not define type parameter 'B' (CS0699)`.

Is there any way to resolve this, or have I really painted myself into a corner?

Comment: Can you just make it a `Box<U>` and pass implementation specific information in through factory methods?

Comment: @MillieSmith removing CRTP would work, of course, but that would result in not being able to control that methods like `Box<B, V> Merge<U, V>(Box<B, U> another, Func<T, U, V> merge)` actually accept compatible `Box`es.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the straight forward fix is the reuse of the `B` type parameter. Try something else, and include it as a type parameter:

```
public abstract Box<B2, U> Transform<B2,U>(Func<T, U> transform) where B2 : Box<B2, U>;
```

Update: you stated:

> now I cannot guarantee that B2 and B are actually the same derived class, which was my goal

This isn't the case though, `B2` does not (cannot?) inherit from `B`, `U` might inherit `T` if you wish. You can include that as a constraint. That's not strictly necessary for the pattern though, since its up to the body of `Transform` to sort it out.

e.g:

```
public abstract Box<B2, U> Transform<B2,U>(Func<T, U> transform) 
    where B2 : Box<B2, U>
    where U : T
```

Comment: Not 100% that you need `B2` instead of `B`, but you definitely need it as a type parameter for `Transform`

Comment: That compiles (if I add B2 to the method's generic parameters), but now I cannot guarantee that B2 and B are actually the same derived class, which was my goal.

Comment: I actually want to ensure that B2 and B are the same class, U and T are completely independent types. Let's say `InfiniteSequence` is one of the derived classes, I want to receive an infinite sequence from the transformation, not an abstract box.

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is that while B and B2 are not the same type, they should be same instance, but without any inheritance relationship between the two right? I don't think you're going to get that. Think about cloning Box and casting T -> U in the process maybe.

Comment: No, I am trying to set the generic constraint that will allow me to override the method in `FooBox<T> : Box<FooBox, T>` using the following signature `FooBox<U> Transform<U>(Func<T, U> transform)`, but not `BarBox<U> Transform<U>(Func<T, U> transform)` or any other child of `Box<B, T>`.